# Start the websocket server automatically on Windows without a visible command prompt window

Tags: laravel, windows, websocket

I want to start a websocket server, like using  the "php artisan websocket:serve", but that automatically start with windows, and without a windows of command prompt. I know how to do it on linux with supervisor, but i need to do that on Windows 7 with Xampp.
I currently use a batch file that starts automatically with Windows, although it works correctly, I wish the command prompt window would not remain permanently visible, since the PC is used for other business stuff, and sometimes the user closes by error the window, stopping the socket server.

Of course, thank you very much for your answers and excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to start windows process without visible console window. First you could create windows service, some software support it natively or you could use utility like [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/). Second: You could start program via task scheduler and tune task properties. Third: You could use utility like [CHP](http://www.commandline.co.uk/chp/) to start program without console window. Remember one thing: If you start program without console window (and it is not a windows service), the only way to stop it is `taskkill` command or GUI Taskmanager.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to solve my problem.
In order to complement the answer given, I will now describe the series of steps I followed to solve the problem:

1) Install NSSM
2) Install the websocket as windows service:
nssm install websocket "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" artisan websocket:serve
nssm set websocket AppDirectory "C:\xampp\htdocs\projectfolder"
nssm set websocket DisplayName "Web Socket Server"
nssm set websocket Description "Web Socket Server for Laravel" 
nssm start websocket
3) Check that the web socket runs:
nssm status websocket

Comment: Hi @FedericoPayes I follow your steps and I succesfully run the service, but when I enter to the webApp this throwme the CORS error, did you use the PID instead of the tipically port 6001?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the websocket server on a windows machine, without the command prompt just set `autoexec.bat` to `halt_threads 2`.